# How to create a new action strip

Tags: nla-editor, actions

I deleted all animations via the blender file outliner and now I cannot add actions in the action editor as there is no action strip. Trying to add a new action strip in the Nonlinear Animation window brings up a search for action strips which is obviously empty. Screenshot below to illustrate.

Thanks[image]

Comment: so what happens when you begin to keyframe a bone?

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that, that created a new strip thanks

Answer (score 1):

as moonboots suggested keyframing a bone generated a new action strip